# How to check if file path is valid in HTML File Input control?

Tags: javascript, file, jsp, input, client-side-validation

I have this html code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>File Upload Example</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="uploadsuccess.jsp" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        Please specify a file:<br/> 
        <input type="file" id="theFile" name="theFile" size="40"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I tried this: I browsed for a file with full filepath: **C:\abc.txt**. Then in physical harddisk, I changed the file name (or moved it to somewhere else). With the File Input textbox still showing "C:\abc.txt", I clicked Submit button and the result is the **uploadsuccess.jsp** is never reached at all. In firefox browser, the tab just reloaded a bit but the page doesn't.

It seems the browser refused to post the data when the file is not found or doesn't exist.

So I want to know how to validate if the inputted filepath is exist or not.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have access to filesystem, but, due to HTML5 File Api specification, there are some file properties that you do have access to, and the file size is one of them. So you could test this. As it is a part of the HTML5 specification, it will only work for modern browsers (and IE is not one of them).

```
//Returns the file size for an form input.
document.getElementById("IdOfyourFileInput").files[0].size;
```

Comment: There is '#' in parameter, is that jQuery syntax?

Comment: @suud ah, yes, I removed it, wanted to indicate that it has to be the ID of the element, too much jQuery in the last weeks.

Comment: so there is no solution in html4?

Comment: This is possible in any browser that supports the File API, means current versions of chrome, firefox, safari, opera. IE10 is the first version of Internet Explorer that supports the File API.

Comment: unfortunately the client still uses older IE :(